# How to save a project to avoid "Project not found" in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How should a whom save their project to be able import without have the error "Project not found"?

EDIT: The files such as .project and .metadata are in the folder, but still getting an error.

Comment: by keeping it in one's workspace and opening the right workspace at startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have `.project` and `.classpath` files available.
Eclipse requires them to make sure project exist.

If that does not help - check paths in files above.

Answer (score 0):

While importing your project select the option ***copy projects into workspace***. Then click finish. If you do so a copy of the project will be in your workspace. So it the other copy is removed also there is no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

.metadata folder that gets created in the workspace is important for the eclipse to identify the projects in the workspace.

Comment: Those file do exist in the folder, but still getting error.

Comment: sometimes while adding the plugins or connecting the project with svn, cvs..the metadata folder gets corrupted. Try to delete the metadata folder and import the projects into workspace again.